# Eclipse RCP 4.x - Defining workspace location

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I know that this question was asked many times, but I didn't find an exact answer which would fulfill my desires :)

Long story short:
I've got simple E4 application, product project, feature and main plugin with simple trim window.

Works, after exporting works too.

Now. I add lifeCycleURI property, create bundleclass for it and create simple dialog with Text area and a Button. Run it\export it and it works, before running main Trim Window dialog is shown. Fine.. Cool etc.

But I want to enter location eg. C:\TEST and after clicking button I want it to be my workspace area for the application (with .metedata and so on). HOW ???

Of course I've tried with :

```
Location instanceLocation = Platform.getInstanceLocation();
instanceLocation.set(new URL("file", null, "C:\TEST"), false);
```

But... It says that I can't change location cause it is already set... Tried to use above in Activator. The same. Tried to add 
`-data @noDefault` in products Launching Arguments ... The same...

I always try to accomplish my tasks by myself but this.... this... ehh... Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in the `@PostContextCreate` method of the life cycle class. Don't specify the '-data' argument

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate()
{   
  Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();

  // Stop if location is set
  if (instanceLoc.isSet())
    return;

  File file = new File("C:\\TEST");

  instanceLocation.set(file.toURL(), false);
}
```

**Note:** You need '\\' in your file path.

This is adapted from code which I use in my e4 RCP.

If you are currently testing the application from within Eclipse you will need to clear the workspace location in the 'Run Configuration' for the application. Open 'Run > Run Configurations', find your application and clear the 'Location' field on the 'Main' tab.

Comment: Cool. but this is exactly my problem :) instanceLoc IS SET .... So i can't change it to my location. 

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change the location once it is set. ... Of course after commenting return; from your snippet :)

Comment: Are you running this from within Eclipse? If so, go to the Run Configuration and clear the 'Location' field - added note on this to the answer.

Comment: Wrote a few comments and found my problem, comments deleted;;. I'm absolutely blind ... I think :) getInstanceLocation .... I always wrote getInst and clicked enter after autosugestion .... yeeeessss..... of course getInstallLocation is before. So your answer is absolutly correct, and my C:\TEST got it's .metadata correctly :) Thanks :D